# OK so i dont get how to make this professor class call on this lecturer class

Tags: python, class, subclass

So i have this code i'm trying to work through first is this

```
class Lecturer (Person):
    def lecture (self, stuff):
        self.say(stuff + "- you should be taking notes")
```

then i'm trying to make a class called professor which calls on this lecture def i made code like this

```
class Professor (Person):
    def profess (self, stuff):
     self.say("Its intuitively obvious that")
```

However here comes the problem i need to bring the lecture def in so that the def profess is calling on it meaning that it adds the first part of the profess to the ending.

ex. X profess "Its intuitively obvious that.....whatever wants to be said - you should be taking notes"

i just dont get how to make it call on it, do you need to put like Lecturer.say (self, stuff) or something of the sort, its apart of my hw to learn python on our own but any help would be appreciated while i continue to work on it myself.

Comment: Two hints:  First, avoid using lots of dots.  "...." doesn't clarify or help.  Second, please use proper code formatting in your question or we won't spend time reading it.

Comment: sorry 'bout that then i'll remove most of the dots but the format is right for python i mean other than the indices cause when you put it in its gonna do it auto.

Comment: "cause when you put it in its gonna do it auto" doesn't really mean anything, does it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want `Professor` to say `"It's intuitively obvious that {} - you should be taking notes".format(stuff)`, as in you want `Professor` to prepend a message to `Lecturer`'s message?

Comment: Yes, thats right i want the Professor to part to be on front and the lecturers part to be on the end....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then Professor should either 'be a' Lecturer or 'have a' Lecturer.

```
class Person(object):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return stuff

class Lecturer(Person):
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return self.say(str(stuff) + " - you should be taking notes")

class Professor1(Lecturer):  # 'is a' Lecturer
    def profess(self, stuff):
        return self.lecture("Its intuitively obvious that "+str(stuff))

class Professor2(Person):  # 'has a' lecturer
    def __init__(self):
        super(Professor2,self).__init__()
        self.lecturer = Lecturer()

    def profess(self, stuff):
        return self.lecturer.lecture("Its intuitively obvious that "+str(stuff))

p1 = Professor1()
print(p1.profess('Earth is flat'))

p2 = Professor2()
print(p2.profess('Earth is flat'))
```

results in

```
Its intuitively obvious that Earth is flat - you should be taking notes
Its intuitively obvious that Earth is flat - you should be taking notes
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you want is to create a subclass.

```
class Lecturer(Person):
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        self.say(stuff + "- you should be taking notes")

class Professor(Lecturer):
    pass
```

Since this is homework, I'll leave you to figure out what to replace `pass` with.